# Android app to parse JSON from website

Tags: java, android, json

Ok, so the first hurdle was cleared in just a few minutes, let's see how this one does.

The code is pulling the JSON data from the website fine as I can see in my log, but now the JSONParser is failing.  I think the issue is JSONObject versus JSONArray, but I can't figure that out.

Here is the data pulled from the JSON site as seen in the log:

```
09-10 09:45:00.175: I/log_tag(785): {"stoker":{"sensors":[{"id":"620000116F01CA30","name":"SS2","al":0,"ta":66,"th":75,"tl":65,"tc":66.3,"blower":null},09-10 09:45:00.175: I/log_tag(785): {"id":"E20000116F0CDB30","name":"brskt2","al":0,"ta":203,"th":32,"tl":32,"tc":70.6,"blower":null}],09-10 09:45:00.175: I/log_tag(785): "blowers":[{"id":"37000000119D8B05","name":"party","on":0}]}}
```

And here is the code trying to parse the data:

```
            try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Sensor resultRow = new Sensor();
                resultRow.id = json_data.getString("id");
                resultRow.name = json_data.getString("name");
                resultRow.current = json_data.getString("tc");
                resultRow.target = json_data.getString("ta");
                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
```

And here is the entry in the log file when it fails:

```
09-10 09:45:00.314: E/log_tag(785): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"stoker":{"sensors":[{"id":"620000116F01CA30","al":0,"tl":65,"tc":66.3,"ta":66,"name":"SS2","blower":null,"th":75},{"id":"E20000116F0CDB30","al":0,"tl":32,"tc":70.6,"ta":203,"name":"brskt2","blower":null,"th":32}],"blowers":[{"id":"37000000119D8B05","on":0,"name":"party"}]}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: Well, because the data is not an json array. It's an JSON object with a key "stoker", etc....

Comment: Can you please put the whole stack trace? That will help you to understand which line is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the JSON string in your logcat is accurate, there are two things that need to change.  First, your result is a JSONObject that contains a JSONArray.  You'll have to make an object first and extract the array from that object.  Secondly, tc and ta are shown as doubles and integers respectively in the output and would need to be retrieved as such.  It'd all look something like this:

```
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject stoker = obj.getJSONObject("stoker");
        JSONArray jArray = stoker.getJSONArray("sensors");
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Sensor resultRow = new Sensor();
            resultRow.id = json_data.getString("id");
            resultRow.name = json_data.getString("name");
            resultRow.current = json_data.getDouble("tc");
            resultRow.target = json_data.getInt("ta");
            arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
```

Based on the provided JSON string, this should work.  For future reference, anything contained within {} is a JSONObject while anything inside of [] is a JSONArray.  Any second value in a key/value pair that has quotes around it is likely a string while values without quotes are retrieved as numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation of Object versus Array.  I thought that was the problem, but your explanation along with the code changes help me understand the difference.  I get a JSONException error that no data is found for sensors, but that will be another issue for another time.

Comment: You should make sure that your JSON string is valid.  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ is a great JSON formatter and validation tool to ensure that your data is properly constructed.  It's completely browser based too, nothing to download.

Also, since your entire output is an object, you might need to get the "stoker object first and get the "sensors" array from that.

Comment: I ran the JSON data through the formatter website and it is valid.  I keep getting an error that no data exists for sensors.  I think you're right about needing to get the stoker object first and the sensors array next, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work.  I'd really appreciate any help you could provide, but understand if this question is dead at this point.  I'm still working on it and will ask a new question is need be.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MCeley- Thank you very much for updating the code.  It works great and you've helped me understand a little more than I did yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t just parse JSON using the Java API without specifying Object or Array — a JSON document can be either. Since your data in the log shows an Object, you need to ask for a JSONObject on your second line.